# Help in linear algebra - system of equation with unknown variable

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this exercise and this type always confuses me.
I have the following system:
[image]

And it asks me to write the matrix, and solve it using Gauss Jordan. After that, I have to see for which values of h the system is solvable.

In the end, solve it for h in R

I solved it like this:

[image]

Now the only thing i can say in my opinion is that the system is not solvable for $h=0$ because in some steps we would be dividing by 0.

Also, if $ h=1 $ then we have an unique solution.

I know how to solve them, but i don't understand where to look for clues of what would be solvable and what not ?

Is it enough to look in the end at the result , or also keep track of the steps and be careful where the system might have infinite solutions , one solution, or impossible ?

Thank you

Comment: When $h=0,$ we have the solution $x=y=z=0$

Comment: How about the case before where i had $ -(h+1)/(2*h) $ ? Isn't that dividing by 0 ?

Comment: Do i have to look for h only in the final solution, or also keep track of steps ? I had different teachers and some of them told me to keep track of steps and where i might be dividing by $0$, or where i might get infinite solutions if i put that variable to a certain value.

Comment: Yes, it is, and it's invalid when $h=0,$ but that doesn't mean the problem can't be solved, just that it can't be solved *that* way.  If you substitute $h=0$ into the original system of equations, you'll see at once that it has a unique solution in that case.

Comment: Okay, i understand that, so in the end, what would be an appropriate answer for this question ? Should i say that $h=0$ and $h=1$ has an unique solution, or should i say that $h=0$ is impossible and $h=1$ has an unique solution ? Anything else ?

Comment: Since we can dispose of the case $h0$ easily, we can assume $h\ne0$ for the rest of the analysis.  The touchy thing is where you divide by $h^3+h+1.$  There is surely a [value of $h$ that makes that $0$.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3%2Bx%2B1%3D0&t=crmtb01)

Comment: Maybe to the question "do rref and say for which h the system is solvable" i should say that for $h=0$ the system is not solvable. And to the other question about 'solve for h in R' i should answer with saying that if $h=0$ or $h=1$ we get one unique solution ?

Comment: For the "problematic"  values - upload them to the original system. E.g. $h=0$ gives one solution, as wrote saulspatz. Here for any $h$ which is not solution to $x^3+x+1=0$ has the system one solution.

Comment: Well the results to that equation are both complex and real. I consider the real one , that would be around $ −0.68233 $, so for that value i cannot solve right ? And for anything other than that value we get one solution, since rank is 3 and null space is 0.

Answer (score 1):

When all the operations are justified, that is, when you haven't divided by $0$, there is a unique solution, and your calculation have produced it.  (I suppose, I haven't checked your work in full detail.)  So, you have to worry about the cases where you've divided by $0$.

One case is $h=0$, but if you substitute that into the original system of equations, you see at once that $x=y=z=0$ is the only solution.  The other case is when you divide by $h^3+h+1$.  If that equals $0$ the system cannot possibly have a solution.  Look at the matrix where you first want to divide by $h^3+h+1.$

The third row would require $0x+0y+0z=h(h+1)$.  If $h^3+h+1=0$, then $h\neq0,-1$ so this equation can't hold.

Comment: So the steps to solve such exercise would be : 1 ) solve with variable h without substituting anything, keep track for any divisions by 0 or where equation might have infinite solutions, one solution etc. 2) once you get the result, look for those cases and substitute those values in h, in the original matrix, and do rref again with that value ? or substitute in the result ? 3 ) analyze the possible outcomes.

Comment: I don't understand when do i substitute, and how do i keep track of those values, that's what confuses me. Do i just go to the end and get a result with h as a variable, then substitute in the result those values that might invalidate the system ? Or values that might give me infinite/unique solution ? And after i substitute i see for which values i get what ?

Comment: Whenever you do a division, you have to remember that you can't divide by $0$.  You should make a note when you divide.  If you divide by $h$, you should write something, like $if h\neq 0.$  When you divide by $h^3+h+1$, you should write, $h\neq0,\,h^3+h+1\neq0$.  Keep track of all the conditions.  When you get to the end, you have to deal with the exceptional cases. How you do that depends on the situation.  Here I used one method for $h=0$ and another for $h^3+h+1=0.$

Comment: Ok so during Gauss Jordan i only have to keep track of divisions by 0 ? Nothing else ? Then in the result, i will deal with that. But what if for example at some point i will get the last row to be h=h , that would mean that if h=0, i get infinite solutions. Do i keep track of those also ?

Comment: Yes, you have to keep track of all anomalies.

Comment: Ok so basically i just need a lot of practice in order to see where a certain value of that variable might produce a certain result, or invalidate the whole system (division by 0) , and in the end, test for those values ? Right ?

Answer (score 0):

The determinant of the matrix of coefficients is $$1(2h)+2h(h^2)+2=2(h^3+h+1)$$

Thus the system has a unique solution iff $$h^3+h+1\ne0$$
You have solved system correctly.

Comment: I don't understand the connection, is it because the volume of the parallelepiped would be $0$ , so a point ? If $h3+h+1=0$ ? How do you solve with the help of determinant ?

Comment: There is the Kramer Rule which used determinants to solve a linear system. The connection is that you can use determinant to figure out when your system is consistent without actually solve the system.

Comment: Ok so after more research i came to this conclusion. For the question "for what h is solvable" i can almost always use cramer's rule , then for the rest i still have to solve and see for which values i get one solution or multiple solutions.

Comment: Anyways in this case i see that $ x= (2*h^3 + 2*h^2 + 2*h)/(2*h^3 + 2*h + 2)$ $y=(- h^3 + h)/(2*h^3 + 2*h + 2)$ and $z=(- 2*h^3 + 2*h^2)/(2*h^3 + 2*h + 2)$ so all 3 coefficients are divided by $(2*h^3 + 2*h + 2)$ , so that is why the determinant must be not 0, otherwise i would be dividing by 0 in cramer's rule and that would be impossible. By doing this i get 3 values for the system, thus an unique solution. Does this help me in any way if i get infinite solutions ? Or for that i have to do Gauss Jordan anyways and analyze specific cases in which i might get those infinite solutions ?

Comment: You get multiple solutions if the determinant is zero and the Kramer Rule results in $0/0$ for one of the variables.  This case does not occur in this particular system.

Answer (score 0):

The system is solvable for all $h\in\mathbb R-{h_0}$ where $h_0$ is a real root of $h^3+h+1=0$.

> Added: As discussed in comments that for $h=0$ the system has trivial solution (can also be obtained from the last step reduced form of matrix).
>
> > For investigation at $h_0$ you just need to clear the fractions first from last step reduced form of matrix by multiplying each row with $h^3+h+1$. At $h=h_0$ $rank(A)=0$ and $rank(A:b)=3$ indicating *no solution* case.

Comment: I don't quite understand the part with $h∈R−h0$. You mean the R field and excluded the real root of $h3+h+1=0.$ That would be R excluded −0.68233 ?

Comment: @AndrewM..yes.I didn't find the root but certainly there exists a real negative root.

Comment: But how about the second question "solve for h in R" does that mean i just have to substitute values other than −0.68233 into the original matrix, and solve the matrix to see what results i get , infinite, or one ? For example i know for $h=1$ i get one result, but also for $h=0$ i get 1 solution, how do i know what and when to substitute in order to find the result, after i find out for which values the system is solvable ? I understood this part. Now how do i go on for the results ?

Comment: Where do i solve for h in R ? Do i substitute in the original matrix then do Gauss Jordan again, or i just substitute in the same result that i got from the Gauss Jordan that i did in my pictures above ?

Comment: Isn't it the same thing ? As long as the system is not invalidated by 0 division, and keep track of rows where i might get all 0 rows , or inconsistent because 1=0, i can just substitute in the end, i should get the same result no ? Or i should just re-do Gauss Jordan with different values as h ?

Comment: From the last step of ur calculations, you have already found the values of $x,y,z$ respectively.

Comment: Yes, but it says solve for h in R, so that would mean he wants all 3 different possibilities, unique solution, no solution or infinite solutions. In this case i get a rank of 3 so it's always gonna be one unique solution if i don't use h = -0.6823. But sometimes in the steps i get for example $-(h+1)/(2*h)$ , so in that step if h=0 then i would be dividing by 0. What do i do with that? In the end if i put h=0 i just get the trivial solution, it is still valid. So does that mean i just keep track of all those anomalies, and then, in the end, i test each value to see if system is valid or not ?

Comment: For any fixed $h$ other than $h_0$ you can always obtain $x,y,z$ by plugging this $h$ in the last reduced matrix of your calculation.

Comment: Yes, in this case i can, but sometimes there are steps in which i get the thing above, division by 0, or maybe there will be a row where if i put a certain $h$ then i will get a row with all $0$'s , that would make it infinite solutions, but then when i do rref, i might divide by that value, and get the row as 1=1 instead of let's say $h+1 = h+1$. So for h = -1 i would get infinite solutions. Do i just keep track of those, then in the last reduced matrix i substitute those values, and see what result i get ?